# Oracle Interval 1 day

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, timestamp, intervals

I would like to understand the difference between

```
someDate >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY)
```

and

```
someDate >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1)
```

Because for me it seems the same, but 2nd one seems to have better perf.

Comment: Add details to your question explaining how #2 "seems" to have better perf. I have a doubt that the time taken to parse and prepare a single value of "1 day ago" for the benefit of then using it to filter in a query will have any discernible effect on the overall query performance at all, unless it is then causing unnecessary type casting of millions of rows

Comment: @CaiusJard: could be caused by the fact that #1 returns a `timestamp` value whereas #2 returns a `date` value. If `someDate` is also a DATE that might influence the use of an index for the query. But only the execution plan for the query could proof that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary difference is that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1` relies on Oracle's ability to perform arithmetic on DATE data type and derive a new date, which is a capability (some) other databases do not support.

Whereas `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY` uses an interval data type to achieve the same end. This is standard syntax and widely supported.

I would expect any perceived performance benefit to one over the other to be an illusion, perhaps caused by the "warm cache" effect.

There is a secondary difference. The use of arithmetic in the second case causes an implicit data conversion and the derived value is a DATE whereas the use of INTERVAL means that the derived value of the first example remains a TIMESTAMP.

```
select dump(current_date) as dt
       ,dump(current_timestamp) as ts 
       ,dump(current_timestamp-1) as ts_arith
       ,dump(current_timestamp - interval '1' day) as ts_invl
       ,dump(current_date - interval '1' day) as dt_invl
from dual
/
```

This could lead lead to a difference in performance, if SOME_DATE is a date type and the column is indexed. In that case comparing to a date might use the index whereas comparing to a timestamp would not.